# Memoize function argument in custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a custom hook that accepts a function. If the function will not change between re-renders/updates, where should I memoize the function?

**OPTION 1**

```
const useCustomHook = (callback) => {
  const callbackRef = useRef();
  callbackRef.current = callback;

  // No effect, this will be re-created every time this hook is called
  // because a new instance of callback is being passed
  const callbackWrapper = useCallback(() => {
    if (callbackRef.current) {
      callbackRef.current();
    }
  }, [callbackRef]);

  // use callbackWrapper
}

const Component = () => {
  // New instance of passed callback will be created each time this component re-renders
  useCustomHook(() => {
    console.log(`I'm being passed to the hook`);
  });

  // ...
  // ...
  return <div></div>;
}
```

**OPTION 2**

```
const useCustomHook = (callback) => {
  // Callback is already memoized
  const callbackRef = useRef();
  callbackRef.current = callback;

  // use callbackRef
}

const Component = () => {
  // Memoized function passed, but
  // 1. Is this allowed?
  // 2. Requires more effort by users of the hook
  useCustomHook(useCallback(() => {
    console.log(`I'm being passed to the hook`);
  }, []));

  // ...
  // ...
  return <div></div>;
}
```

Option 2 seems more valid but it requires users of the custom hook to first enclose their function in a `useCallback()` hook. Is there an alternative way where users don't need to enclose the passed function in `useCallback()`?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use the `useEffect` hook to "memoize" the `callback` to the React ref.

```
const useCustomHook = (callback) => {
  const callbackRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    // only update callback saved in ref if callback updates
    callbackRef.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // provide stable callback that always calls latest
  // callback stored in ref
  const callbackWrapper = useCallback(() => {
    if (callbackRef.current) {
      callbackRef.current();
    }
  }, []);

  // use callbackWrapper
}
```

Or use `useMemo` or `useCallback` directly, but at this point you are essentially just redefining `useMemo` or `useCallback` in your custom hook. In this case, pass an additional dependency array argument.

```
const useCustomHook = (callback, deps) => {
  const callbackWrapper = useMemo(() => callback, deps);

  // use callbackWrapper
}
```

This being said, you will likely want to be in the habit of memoizing callbacks that are being passed down *before* they are passed, in order to guaranteed provided stable references. This way you won't need to go through the rigamarole of the weirdness of your custom hook.

Comment: @dracodormiens That's completely normal when using React refs, and also what the `if (callbackRef.current)` condition is for.

Comment: I need to use `callbackWrapper` immediately and not defer it to after first render. `useEffect` will only initialize it after the first render is complete.

Comment: @dracodormiens To be quite honest your custom hook seems a little (*trivially*) pointless. Have you a more concrete example for what you are trying to do and how you want to use it?

Comment: `useCustomHook` is basically `useEventListener()`. And `// use callbackWrapper` is an immediate call to `window.addEventListener()`. For this example, I've skipped `removeEventListener()` cleanup. Now, if the passed listener is not changed, the event listener must not be removed and re-attached.

Comment: @dracodormiens I see. Can you basically update your question to include the more representative code you've an issue and/or question about? With event listeners you typically attach them *once* when the component mounts, and remove them during cleanup, but if you need to fix stale enclosures then you should use a dependency and reinstantiate the event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Another other way is to declare the callback outside of the component body ( but I don't recommend that, It can create some edge cases )

```
function cb () {
  console.log(`I'm being passed to the hook`);
}

const Component = () => {

  useCustomHook(cb);

  // ...
  // ...
  return <div></div>;
}
```

<s>memoize the function in you want on top level component body and then pass it to your custom hook like this:</s>

```
const Component = () => {
  // hooks should be called on top level function body
  const cb = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(`I'm being passed to the hook`);
  }, []);

  useCustomHook(cb);

  // ...
  // ...
  return <div></div>;
}
```

Comment: How is this different than OP's option 2, other than the obvious "non-inline" use of `useCallback`?

Comment: @DrewReese not much different, justing fixing the obvoius problem; https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level    we don't have to over complicate an industry standard solution to show we know something.

Comment: And what was the problem? No hooks are called from loops, conditions, or nested functions. The `useCallback` hook is called in a function component. Code, albeit a little unconventional, is syntactically correct and breaks no rules of hooks. If you don't believe it check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-mclean-iclcu?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: @DrewReese yeap it is the same thing; not problematic; I was wrong; thank you for pointing out 